# Blender Won't Open

Tags: osx

I downloaded Blender onto my Mac laptop, but it will not open. When I try to open it, I get an error message that says, *"'Blender' can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."* I'm not sure what to do to get it to open. :/

Comment: What version of blender did you download?

Comment: probably a test build.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences.

[image]

Then go to Security & Privacy

[image]

Click on "Open Anyway"

[image]

Comment: Consider marking this as answer or upvote it if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Mac problem, not a Blender problem. I am a fellow Mac user and have dealt with this myself.

You probably have an error something like this:

[image]

After trying to open an application several times, you should see the above image, which also includes an *Open* button. Click that. You should not see the error again unless (occationally) when you restart your computer or redownload Blender. You can also attempt to open the application by right-clicking on the Blender icon in your dock and selecting *Open*:

[image]

Comment: From macOS High Sierra, You most probably won't get that "Open" button.